# static <a href=""> not working correctly in my project

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

my website had two static URL placed at header sections that used to switch between home page and contact page. I found out that it is working well when I logged in as admin but these two links not working after I logged out. The problem is that it only dynamically render content area once I click on the link. I need every click I made will jump to another page. But currently, it looks like it didn't make a new request and refresh the page. I don't know what's happening about it. Please help me out I am so struggling about it.[image]

Comment: Did you rebuild cache after your changes?

Comment: How are those links placed on the page ? block ? view ? custom module ? Please reformat your question in more understandable pieces of text.

Comment: Helli guys, the static url has been put into a block which contains user information. It did working correct when I logged as admin but didnt work corrrect when I logged out admin role. It looks not jump another page and only dynamically change the main content area (middle section) and keep footer and heaader not rerendered.

Comment: I did clear cache but problem still not solved.

Comment: Is it custom module? if you inspect you inspect element code, whe will you see as in "href" of url?

Comment: This project write in my custom theme. I didnt write any custom module. The a tag is correctly formated when I inspect elements.

Comment: Guys, I just found that the cause of this problem might be the version of jquery I include in the project. The drupal 8 might only adapt to jquery version 3. Because once I change jquery version from 2 to 3 then links working correctly.